# How to add an internal package for types with Turborepo?

Tags: javascript, typescript, monorepo, pnpm, turborepo

I've  been trying to create an internal package for my Monorepo based on Turborepo. I am running Nuxt 3 with Tailwind. Now my Issue is that I am trying to create a custom package for types. I tried following the guide on https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/sharing-code/internal-packages but that did not work at all. Ive tried a few other things but nothing worked out.

Does someone have a detailed guide I could follow to create an Internal Types package for my typescript interfaces so that I can use them across my App Web folder and packages / ui components folder. (Also running PNPM)

I've  tried to follow the guide multiple times, it never worked. I also tried to add the typescript interfaces via the `tsconfig` include option, but that did not work either (I likely did a lot of things wrong).

Answer (score 3):

Your custom package for `types` will be very similar to `ui` or any other package.

Steps to follow:

1. Create a folder `my-types` inside packages.
2. Create `src` folder and add your types files in it. e.g.  `my-type-a.ts` and `my-type-b.ts`
3. Add `index.ts` file in the root of `my-types` package to export all types files. Just add `export * from "./src"` in it.
4. Create a `package.json` file. Add `main` and `types` file source in it. Like this

[image]

Now you can import types in your other packages and apps. Just add this `my-types` new packages in the dependencies and you will be able to import `types` or `interfaces` in it.

Comment: This is work only for development. But when I try to build, it will shows error. Where the `my-types` packages need to has build script. How you handle that?